# How to mix and merges audios in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I want to make a program that can merge and mix music with python.
I'm trying to use pydub, the only library I found for this purpose (if you have a similar or easier to use library, I welcome recommendations). But I can't open the file, it always says that ffmpeg was not found. I've used pip install ffmpeg, as I saw on a site, but it still doesn't work.
If anyone has a better solution or a way to solve the problem, I'd appreciate it.
So far, my code is like this:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound1 = AudioSegment.from_mp3("musics/sound1.mp3")
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_mp3("musics/sound2.mp3")

output = sound1.overlay(sound2, position=5000)

output.export("mixed_sounds.mp3", format="mp3")
```

Comment: Do you have ffmpeg installed on your system ?

Comment: The git page for that lib has these instructons: https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#getting-ffmpeg-set-up

Comment: @TGrif I used a "pip install fmpeg" on cmd. I also downloaded a .7z file from ffmpeg.org (for Windows) and put it in the same folder as my .py code. But it hasn't worked yet...